# Docker compose not picking up env variables

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have a solution which contains 2 microservices (Product & Review). Each of the 2 API projects have a Dockerfile defined, here is an example of the review dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src

ENV ConnectionString:Review="Data Source=db,1433;Initial Catalog=Review;uid=sa;pwd=TesT111t!;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

COPY ["Review.Api/Review.Api.csproj", "Review.Api/"]
COPY ["Review.Data/Review.Data.csproj", "Review.Data/"]
COPY ["Review.Service/Review.Service.csproj", "Review.Service/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Review.Api/Review.Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Review.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Review.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Review.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Review.Api.dll"]
```

As you can see the dockerfile contains an env variable `ConnectionString`.

I have a breakpoint in the startup of the review api project to inspect what is inside the `Configuration`, here is what the file looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ReviewDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Review")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(FindProductReviews));
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(FindReview));
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ReviewController));
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(ProductController));
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(FindProductReviews.Handler).Assembly);
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(FindReview.Handler).Assembly);
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(CreateReview.Handler).Assembly);
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
    }
}
```

My solution has a `docker-compose` file and when running `docker-compose up -d` the breakpoint is hit, however when looking inside the `Configuration` their is no connection string which is defined like the one in the dockerfile.

I feel like im missing something small, I've looked at the documentations and cannot find what I'm missing

Comment: Linux environment variable names have to use the double underscore section delimiter and not a colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Application initial configuration

First of all, please confirm that, when your program starts, you are building your configuration such as below (typical setups), in order to bind it with env.variables.

```cs
// Defining a configuration that explicitly uses env. variables
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            ...
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
```

or

```cs
// The default builder already adds env. variables
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            ...
```

#### Docker

Please, replace `ConnectionString:Review` by `ConnectionString__Review` (reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables)).

If you want to keep on setting the env.variable in your `Dockerfile`, you can move it to the last section `final`, such as:

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ConnectionString__Review="Data Source=db,1433;Initial Catalog=Review;uid=sa;pwd=TesT111t!;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Review.Api.dll"]
```

However, to enhance decoupling, you may prefer to set the variable in your `docker-compose` file.

You may also consider using the `appsettings` JSON files, since they allow much flexibility across environments.

#### Multiple connection configurations

If your services are able to access shared configurations, but also have their own, then, you can specify proper names to each configuration, to ensure that any mistake happens :)

Comment: I've placed it after the final but still don't get the env variable?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer for clarity, please see if it fits. Me and my colleagues do something similar in some projects

Comment: I'm still not getting it for some reason? It's rather strange, I'll try adding another env variable to see if thats picked up

Comment: I didn't notice the `:`. Please, try a variable only with alphanumeric characters (`_` also accepted)

Comment: I'll edit again, sorry, didn´t notice. Please, replace `:` by double underscores `__`. The reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables)

Comment: I don't understand what I'm missing as its still not working, I'm inspecting the environment variables in `Configuration` and the connection string variable isn't there

Comment: Does the env.variable exist in the running container?

Comment: I just had a look and it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

You only define the `ENV` variable in the `build` image.  If you follow the `FROM` chain, the `final` image is built `FROM base`, and `COPY --from=build`, but the `COPY` only copies files and not environment variables or other metadata.

Your question title and tags hint at a Compose-based setup.  Connection information like the database host name and (especially) credentials need to be configured at deployment time, not part of the image.  I'd remove this line from your `Dockerfile` entirely, and instead include it in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db: { ... }
  app:
    environment:
      - ConnectionString:Review=Data Source=db,1433;Initial Catalog=Review;uid=sa;pwd=TesT111t!;Integrated Security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
    ...
```

Comment: I see, but then how do I define multiple connection strings as I have more than 1 service (Product and Review)

Comment: In the Compose file you can declare a separate database for each service and a corresponding connection string, if that's what you need.